# covariance matrix of any ARMA(p,q)

Tags: time-series, variance

Assume I have an ARMA(p,q) weakly stationary process with the error term $\epsilon_{w}$ such that $\epsilon \sim WN(0,\sigma^2_w)$, can either be gaussian or non-gaussian. The covariance matrix,$M$ is built based on the auto-covariance function of the ARMA(p,q) process in the form of $\sum \sigma^2_w K$ where the process $K$ is just the construct of the coefficients from the ARMA(p,q) process. So my question is since all elements in the $M$ covariance matrix involve the constant $\sigma^2_w$, is it viable to write the covariance matrix as a product of the white noise variance as $\sigma^2_w * M$ where $M$ is just a $n \times n$ matrix with values depending on the coefficients of the ARMA(p,q) process.

Thanks

Edit: If this is true, any reference that can confirm would be excellent as well.